# How to add facebook application specific data to a facebook user

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have built a facebook appliaction which reads facebook user friends' data. To each of these friends we want to add some application specific fields such as their anniversary date, engagement date, wedding date etc.

Is it possible to add this data using Facebook API? If so, Please let us know how to do it or point us in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot add bits of "profile data" like this. You can:

1) Store this data on your own server, in your own database. Associate it with some table of users in your app, which you can tie to their user ID so that you can also associate it with their FB information.

2) Use the Open Graph API (newly announced still in "beta", but you can start using it) to push custom stories to Facebook, but these are more meant to be ways of logging content that a user has interacted with, such as "Joe listened to Beethoven's 9th Symphony."

Comment: This is correct - you must store additional information ued by your app on your own.

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand is you want to add new type of fields like "Engagement date" to Facebook profile. If so it is not possible. Facebook site itself doesn't contains these features. Facebook API actually exposes features in normal website to an application developer.